# How to store a passphrase to decrypt a secure data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, cookies, encryption

I have a passphrase to decrypt a data using a public key in my rails application.

I ask to the user the "passphrase" when this user try to go to a specific menu (e.g. "invoicing") in order to decrypt the sensible data.

It's not recommended to store the passphrase directly to the user session/cookie (for the security reason).

So, what's the best way to store this passphrase without a security hole ?

Comment: Can you just explain how long you want to store this for? Do you need to store it across requests, or longer term than this? Do they need to un-encrypt all data, or just one bit at a time?

Comment: I need to store my passphrase accross requests. When the user session is expired, the user needs to enter again the correct passphrase to a form to access to the sensible data.

Comment: If this is a rails web application, is the user sending his passphrase over an unsecured http connection? If so, an attacker can capture it and impersonate the user. Why can't this communication be protected with https?

Comment: HTTPS does not solve the problem. My passphrase stay without any security on the user's cookie => that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way is to use the Encrypted cookie store. You can find more information about that on this article :

Encrypted cookie store [here](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/encrypted_cookie_store) and [here](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/04/13/announcing-encryptedcookiestore-plugin-for-rails-2-3/)

[Here](https://github.com/FooBarWidget/encrypted_cookie_store), the github of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

- Your requirement is that the user can enter their pass-phrase once, and then access all their data for the remainder of their session.
- You have a large quantity of data to encrypt per account (i.e. more than one invoice).

I'd do something like the following:

- Encrypt all the data attached to the user's account using a secure, random key (data key) and a symmetric cipher (e.g. AES).
- Give each account a public/private key (account key), with a user chosen passphrase.
- Encrypt the data key using the public account key, and store it.
- Create an application wide secure random key (session key).
- When the user keys in their pass phrase, use it to decrypt their data key, and then immediately re-encrypt this with the session key, and store it in their session or a cookie. Separately store a timestamp in the session noting when the key was encrypted, and sign this by creating a hash of the timestamp, the encrypted data key and the session key.

When they want to look at some data, then:

- Pull the encrypted data key, timestamp and signature hash out of the session. Recalculate the hash based on the timestamp, encrypted data key and session key, and check that it matches the hash from the session (i.e. that nothing has been tampered with).
- Compare the timestamp to 'now', and decide whether this is recent enough that you're going to trust it (i.e. that it hasn't been stolen by a man in the middle attack).
- If and only if that's ok, decrypt the data key using the session key.
- Use the data key to decrypt the data.

If you want extra security, you could rotate the session key regularly to ensure that even if an attacker manages to get hold of an encrypted data type from someone's session, they'd have to compromise the application itself *at the same time* in order to get the relevant session key.

This might well be over complex for your needs. If not, then please bear in mind that I'm no cryptographer, so use this at your own risk, and get someone who really knows what they're doing here if you're at all concerned!

Hope that helps.